# Can any one please help me understand How to do incremental build in Jenkins?

Tags: jenkins, gradle, incremental-build

I am using gradle and want to do a incremental build on jenkins,I am not sure how to proceed,If any can advise me some good documentation or proper way to proceed.

Many thanks

Comment: I am not sure what are you looking for. It's kind of practice in software engineering. Instead of building the whole software and release it altogether, add some new features on top of some existing features. This is called incremental ....

Comment: Yes, exactly. You can also skip `clean` task so it'll speed up the build.

Answer (score 0):

In general it should be simple to do a incremental build with gradle. you just need to configure your job to update your working copy from your vcs and invoke the gradle command. In gradle `incremental buld` means that if the inputs for parts of your software (e.g. some subprojects) havn't changed and the output is still there, the according tasks will be marked as up-to-date.

In the past I discovered a problem with skipping tasks of type `Test` in jenkins because jenkins complains about the test reports that are older than the triggered build job. You can fix that in your gradle build by using the following snippet:

```
task testJenkins(dependsOn: test) {
   description '=== Update the timestamp of the test results also if UP-TO-DATE ==='
   inputs.files test.outputs.files
   doLast{
      def timestamp = System.currentTimeMillis()
      testResultsDir.eachFile { it.lastModified = timestamp }
   }
   check.dependsOn(testJenkins)
}
```

Comment: Thanks Rene,so far what I understand is that it is very much possible and it is same as any build on jenkins,but output reports and all which were there from past build may create problem and we need to address those in a separate way?

Comment: I would start by just using gradle in an incremental way (running just `gradle build` for example. if that causes issues with jenkins, you'll definitely find a workaround with gradle for that. Even better: raise an issue in the jenkins issue tracker as it seems to make wrong assumptions here.